# Breeze does not generate ko observables

Tags: knockout.js, breeze

I have the following problem with a simple MVC4 + ko + breeze webapp:
the breeze entities returned by a query are simple javascript objects, without ko observables.
I inspected the todo sample (which correctly returnes ko observables) and I didn't find the place where breeze is configured to work with ko (and generate observables).
I tried adding the following lines, but nothing changed:

```
var core = breeze.core;
var entityModel = breeze.entityModel;

core.config.setProperties({
    trackingImplementation:     entityModel.entityTracking_ko,
    remoteAccessImplementation: entityModel.remoteAccess_webApi
});
```

Thanks in advance for Your kind help

Comment: I'm having the same problem. Using the latest nuget package. My code looks like: [code]var serviceName = 'api/WebApi';
            var manager = new breeze.EntityManager(serviceName);
            var query = new breeze.EntityQuery()
                .from("Perspectivas"); manager.executeQuery(query)
                .then(function (data) {
                    alert("a");
                })
                .fail(function (error) {
                    toastr.error("Ha ocurrido un error al obtener los datos: " + error.message);
                });[code]

Comment: hy, did it work with an earlier version of breeze? Did you get ko observables before the update? tnx :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

gotcha!
the problem was in a couple of missing attributes in the WebApi controller:

```
[JsonFormatter, ODataActionFilter]
public class MyController : ApiController
{
    // my methods...
}
```

After adding [JsonFormatter, ODataActionFilter] the returned entities had the expected ko observables!

Comment: My problem was that the models were not in the same namespace that my context.

Comment: Yikes! I just spent over an hour trying to debug an issue in which KnockoutJS stopped working. It took me a while to realize the problem was that KnockoutJS wasn't working. I'd relocated my Repository class (context) too and - thanks to Julian, fixed the issue in 5 minutes after reading his comment. Thanks Julian!

Answer (score 4):

@frenchfraso - It may be worth knowing of a few improvements in Breeze since you wrote your code.

The `entityModel` namespace is deprecated and everything that was on it has been elevated to `breeze`. The `entityModel` namespace still works ... but you want to get rid of it when you have the time.  Here's how you'd create an EntityManager today:

```
  var manager = new breeze.EntityManager(serviceName);
```

Knockout is now the default "modelLibrary" adapter and Web API is the default "dataservice" adapter so you no longer have to configure breeze core.

That means you can ***simply delete every line of the code*** in your question :)

There is a new syntax to specify a non-default Breeze adapter. Here's an example that configures Breeze to use the Backbone model library instead of Knockout:

```
  breeze.core.config.initializeAdapterInstances({modelLibrary: "backbone"});
```

Comment: Really helpful answer, Ward may be helpful to throw a comment in the Edmunds sample for idiots like me that you don't need to specify this anymore if you are using Knockout.

Answer (score 4):

My problem was that I have loaded knockout AFTER breeze and therefore breeze returned me POJO objects.

```
<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/q.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/breeze.debug.js"></script>    
<script src="Scripts/knockout-2.1.0.debug.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/toastr.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/require.js" data-main="App/main"></script>
```

After changing the load order breeze returned KO observables:

```
<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/q.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/knockout-2.1.0.debug.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/breeze.debug.js"></script>    
<script src="Scripts/toastr.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/require.js" data-main="App/main"></script>
```

Comment: While this may not have contributed to this solution, nearly a year later and it saved me. Thank you!