# Breeze data not observable in Metadatastore Post Entity Constructor Function

Tags: javascript, c#, entity-framework, knockout.js, breeze

The goal is to apply an untracked computed `FullName` function, to an Entity. This Entity is passed to the client, and is bound using knockout. I am applying the [recommended method](http://breeze.github.io/doc-js/extending-entities.html) by linking an Initializer function to the metadatastore Entity registration constructor.

```
    // The Entities are being created on the client side.
    var metadataStore = manager.metadataStore;
    metadataStore.registerEntityTypeCtor('Doctor', null, DoctorInit);

    function DoctorInit(doctor) {
        // The whole entity is passed to the function, but
        // the properties are not observable.
        doctor.FullName = ko.computed(function () {
            // Err: doctor.FirstName is not a function
            return doctor.FirstName() + " " + doctor.LastName();
        });
    }
```

When the `FullName` property is accessed by the viewmodel, an error is thrown saying that `doctor.FirstName` is not a function, so I checked the properties to make sure that they were observable using `ko.isObservable`, and they were not observable.

An Interesting dilemma considering that the data can be updated and saved by the client. I simply cannot apply untracked computed observables. How do I fix this problem. Is there a hook into breeze that can assure me that knockout is present and functioning?

### Troubleshooting

According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13582107/breeze-does-not-generate-ko-observables) Breeze will not apply observables if Breeze is loaded before knockout is loaded, so I confirmed that knockout is being loaded first.

Knockout Loads Before Breeze:

[image]